# Sorting rows in a Gtk.ListBox

Tags: python, sorting, gtk

I'm trying to sort rows in a `Gtk.ListBox` based on a search query. It seems that GTK has a native way of doing this with `set_sort_func()`, however I can't find any good examples on how to use it. Could someone provide an example of how this may be done?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what version of Gtk you're using, so I'm going to assume it's Gtk4. Below is a minimal example code for how to use the sort function in a **Gtk.ListBox**.

Warning: This function cannot be used if the **Gtk.ListBox** is built based on a model.

```py
    import random
    from gi.repository import Gtk
    import gi
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
    
    
    class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=10)
            self.set_child(self.box)
    
            self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Insert Row")
            self.box.append(self.button)
    
            self.set_default_size(800, 600)
    
            self.list_box = Gtk.ListBox.new()
            self.list_box.set_sort_func(self.sort_function)
    
            self.box.append(self.list_box)
    
            self.button.connect('clicked', self.add)
    
        def add(self, button):
    
            number = random.randint(0, 100)
            row = self.row_setup(f"test {number}", f"{number} ")
    
            self.list_box.append(row)
    
        def sort_function(self, one, two):
    
            one_number = int(one.get_child().get_first_child().props.label)
            two_number = int(two.get_child().get_first_child().props.label)
    
            if one_number < two_number:
                return -1
            elif one_number > two_number:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
    
        def row_setup(self, title, number):
    
            row = Gtk.ListBoxRow.new()
            row_box = Gtk.Box()
            row_title = Gtk.Label.new(title)
            row_number = Gtk.Label.new(number)
            row_box.append(row_number)
            row_box.append(row_title)
            row.set_child(row_box)
    
            return row
    
    
    class MyApp(Gtk.Application):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)
    
        def on_activate(self, app):
            self.win = MainWindow(application=app)
            self.win.present()
    
    
    app = MyApp(application_id="com.example.GtkApplication")
    app.run(None)
```